# Android - How to make my application not to be garbage collected ever?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I am developing one `sample application`.

I want this application should not be garbage collected ever until i switch off the phone.

```
1. Is this is possible in android?
2. If it is possible. How can i do this?
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible in Android. And there is a good reason for it : system manages memory as a limited resource and no application can remain active if not used to ensure memory is available to other apps.

Nevertheless, technically, you can use a foreground service to ask the system to keep your application running as long as possible, possibly longer than a "normal" app with no such a service.

But, all in all, what you want to achieve is not a good idea. The Android way is to create your app, persist its state and re-set new instances of your app in the same state. For persisting state there are multiple solutions like using SharedPreferences, files or a database.